# how to get text from radiobutton in string and check whether it is empty or not

Tags: android, android-button

What is the error in `radioButton1.getText().toString().equals("")` in code below?

I want to force the user to fill in this field and if he leaves the field empty then toast a message that fills the required field. How do I do this?

```
page1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 

public void onClick(View v) { 
    if(radioButton1.getText().toString().equals("")||radioButton2.getText().toString().equals("")||radioButton3.getText().toString().equals("")||radioButton4.getText().toString().equals("")
||petn.getText().toString().equals("")||breed.getText().toString().equals("")||color.getText().toString().equals("")||alergic.getText().toString().equals("")||ath_locat.getText().toString().equals("")||d_condi.getText().toString().equals("")||weight1.getText().toString().equals("")
    )
    { 
    Log.e("onclick", ",pd"); 
    Toast msg = Toast.makeText( 
    My2Activity.this,"Please fill the * required field",Toast.LENGTH_LONG); 
    msg.show(); 
     } 
    else{ 
    PostData(); 
    Intent d = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), 
    My1Activity.class); 
    startActivity(d); 
    } 
    } 
    });
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. And more than that , why do you need to take text from radiobutton??? take the option and check ma8

Comment: what do u mean by filling radioButton? can u give more clear idea or screen shot

Comment: @RajeshRajaram friend i have some fields that i want to be field by the users and if they leave the field empty then on click button it toast a message that field should not be empty, for this i want to check weather radiobutton is selected or not

Comment: the user can fill in only edit texts, or you can check radiobutton is checked or not, there is no way you can type in a radiobutton

Comment: @CRDave i have some fields that i want to be field by the users and if they leave the field empty then on click button it toast a message that field should not be empty, for this i want to check weather radiobutton is selected or not

Comment: @RajeshRajaram then what is the syntax to check weather radiobutton is selected or not

Comment: @ManishSharma check in answer

Comment: @ManishSharma Please google how to use radiobuttons before posting a question here

Comment: @MoJo I have used radiobuttons properly and getting good results, but now i want to manipulate my code thats why i asked question, either u dont understand my question or i am unable to make u understand my question

Comment: @ManishSharma: not only me, most of us here find it difficult to understand your question, pls add more precision to your explanation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(radioButton1.isChecked())
{

}
else
{

}
```

you want to set OnCheckedChangeListener to radio button

```
radioButton1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioButton.OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) 
{

}
}
```

Comment: I understand your answer buddy, now can you please tell me how to do this thing with radio group, if i have 3 radiobuttons in radiogroup then one element must be selected how to achieve this condition

Comment: @ManishSharma try this example bro http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-radio-buttons-example/
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioButton.html

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
radioButton1.isChecked()
```

Comment: I think you should extend and explain your answer a little bit.

Comment: What @Manish Sharma wants to do is to check whether the radio button is checked or not.
So the given code will return true if the radio button is checked else will return false.

Comment: Please link the documentation of the `isChecked()` function for example.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 I want to check weather radiogroup items are selected or not can you please tell me about that

Comment: @RajeshRajaram: Please provide an authorative link, like the Android API documentation or an example from the Android SDK or something like that, so that the one who asked the question is able to actually learn where to solve these problems.

Comment: @Manish Sharma: For radio group try in you if condition this code :- radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1

Comment: @I understand your answer buddy, now can you please tell me how to do this thing with radio group, if i have 3 radiobuttons in radiogroup then one element must be selected how to achieve this condition

Comment: In radio group, I think only one button can be selected out of all.

Comment: @ManishSharma: The group is documented here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RadioGroup.html , the method is called `getCheckedRadioButtonId()`.

Comment: @AnujMathur_07 i have voted this  (radiogroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()==-1) as useful, but not worked for me, by using this it is not showing error but not working also. but i want something like this, for example i used this(radiobutton1==null) where radiobutton1 is created by ( int selectedId1 = radioGroup1.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 // find the radiobutton by returned id
  //radioButton1=null;
  
    radioButton1 = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId1);)
so please give something effective by which i can do what i want...

Comment: You can try this :-      radioGroup1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

   @Override
   public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
    isChecked = true;
   }
  });
... Where isChecked is a boolean variable whose default value will be false. Now use this variable 'isChecked' in your if condition.